# Playing Multiple Sound Files

Tags: asterisk, dialplan

I would really like some help with this one.

I have a requirement to play an audio file, read the numeric values and end playing another audio file all on the one line, can this be done in the dialplan?

For example I want to be able to say.

You have a incoming call for(playing) & 15 (read minutes) & minutes(playing). I need to put this into the Dial() string as the mA.

Answer (score 0):

You have macro and gosub procedures for that.

```
 M(macro[^arg[^...]]):
 U(x[^arg[^...]]):
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Dial

Etc.

If that not works for you, you have rewrite app dial.